# How to make docker-compose build image once and repeatedly use it to run containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run multiple containers built from the same image. My problem is when I define my `docker-compose.yml` this way

```
version: '3'
services:
    crossbar-target:
        container_name: "app-crossbar-target"
        build:
            context: ../../crossbar

    crossbar-source-domain1:
        container_name: "app-crossbar-source-domain1"
        build:
            context: ../../crossbar

    crossbar-source-domain2:
        container_name: "app-crossbar-source-domain2"
        build:
            context: ../../crossbar
```

I will get three containers as I want them, but I get three images as well.

In case I have hundreds of containers, I don't like the idea having hundreds of images as well. That makes my local image repository completely unusable and unreadable.

Thinking and searching for solution I tried define crossbar image by itself and then reuse it:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app-crossbar:
        build:
        context: ../../crossbar

    crossbar-target:
        container_name: "app-crossbar-target"
        image: project_name/app-crossbar

    crossbar-source-domain1:
        container_name: "app-crossbar-source-domain1"
        image: project_name/app-crossbar

    crossbar-source-domain2:
        container_name: "app-crossbar-source-domain2"
        image: project_name/app-crossbar
```

Now, I have only one image for all containers, but get an app-crossbar container as well. That doesn't suit my needs as well.

Is there any way to make `docker-compose` manage my images efficiently and make only those images I need and then use them to run containers in any amount needed? Or do I have to manage my images separately in some other routines? I like calling:

```
docker-compose build
```

to rebuild all needed images and I like the idea that all my docker logic is held in one place.

Comment: It appears that whatever is built in `../../crossbar` serves as a base image. Hence, you may want to only build that image on your own and register it in a private registry. Build that base image regulary/on-demand in a cronjob / jenkins job, and use it in your docker-compose file. Each service you define will have its own container. You cannot get around that.

Comment: Each service having its own container is no problem (actually a need), but having own image for each container is really messy. Is there a way to let docker-compose manage my images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build the `crossbar` image first and properly tag it. Then you can spawn multiple services using that image. The `latest` tag here is only an example. I would use a unique version number.

```
version: '3'
services:
    app-crossbar:
        image: crossbar:latest

    crossbar-target:
        image: crossbar:latest

    crossbar-source-domain1:
        image: crossbar:latest

    crossbar-source-domain2:
        image: crossbar:latest
```

A huge advantage of pre-building images (and possibly storing them in an docker image repo) is that you can revert to older versions when needed. In addition you can run tests with the pre-build images if needed.

It's pretty standard to have a CI setup where for example Jenkins builds a new image of your `crossbar` project (when you push a branch), properly tags it an pushes the image to your private (or public) image repo.

I'd say even if you **could** build the image with compose, that is still not the right way to do it for prod. It might be acceptable if you extend your image to add a layer with config files. By pre-building images your pipeline is also compatible with swarm and other clustered environments.

If this is overkill for your needs you just build locally (and TAG the images properly). The tagging part is important so you don't have to battle with docker cache and you can still find older versions if a revert is needed.

*(In a dev environment you can be a more careless and just map in directories and file from the host to the containers. No one wants to re-build for every single change)*

Comment: But can I let docker-compose to handle my crossbar image? I would like to have everything in one place and don't have to maintain my images separately. I like calling docker-compose up to take care of everything...

Comment: You maintain your images separately. Normally you'd have a build system createing the images pushing them to a private docker image repository. Your compose setup then only selects what version to use.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll wait if anyone finds a way and accept if not.

Comment: As the others said, you have to manage the local images by your own. Just push the images you need to a private or public registry. You can setup a cleanup cron job for example which would run `docker system  prune` to cleanup all not used/dangling local images. The answer of @Grimmy is correct.